# 3D sound with javascript on Canvas

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-canvas

I would like to know if it is in anyway possible to create a 3D sound effect with JS?

The idea is hanging sounds to objects that you can drag around a canvas.
If you drag the object to the right of the canvas, the comes from you right box, and vice versa.

Ditto for up and down. The sound must become quieter when the object is up, and louder when the object is down.

Does anybody has an idea of a library I can use to make that happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this article on HTML5 Rocks about positional audio, I believe that is exactly what you need:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/positional_audio/

There are some really nice demos